# Create a folder backed by software rather than OS?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, directory

I recently got put on a project where they're having issues with too many files in a folder slowing down access.  I believe it is 10,000+ files in a single folder where windows starts to slow down access, we have something on the order of 50,000.  All the files are small and most of the time we only need to access the newest .1-2.% of them via windows file and print sharing.  I'd look into dividing the files into subfolders, except that there is a bunch of legacy code that is only able to look at a single folder.

My idea - I don't know if it is possible or even plausible - is to create a small program that buffers the newest .1-.2% files in memory, and retrieves the rest from disk as needed.

1. I had thought that years ago I'd read of a protocol that could simulate a folder on a hard drive.  Is it possible?
2. Is there something out there that already does this?  Is there a better option without major changes to the system?
3. What to other systems use for serving up a large number of files?  Is there some other product that serves files that we could map as a network drive?  Or some way to blend 2 folders so they look like one?

Comment: You're not able to update the legacy code to search more than one folder? I'd have thought that'd be simplest. Yes, what you're talking about should be possible, although I'm not sure you'd be able to do it  all in user mode - you'd need to create a filesystem driver and then junction it in in the right place. That'd be a lot more effort.

Comment: That was my first question too, but no, it's not my code and the higher-ups don't want it changed for the moment.

Comment: Right. I still think it's the correct thing to do though, and you shouldn't take that as a flat "no". Unless you get any other solutions here you need to put together a good case to take to your manager why changing the legacy code is simplest, quickest and least risk overall.

Comment: There's a host of issues at play here; if the legacy code is the part that's become slow, the only place to fix it is in the legacy code. 50K files is way too many to manage in a single NTFS folder. If it's only explorer access that's slow... use the command line. The combination of issues to address here is too complex to give a simple "yeah, a custom caching filesystem driver will handle this" response... because it *could*, but the cost of developing FS drivers for a server environment is probably higher than fixing the legacy code. It's a cost issue.

Comment: If you cannot change the code then you cannot fix the problem.  If they won't change the code, they won't approve an unproven and untested application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside the *"correct way to solve this problem"* for the moment, what you're looking for is called "[Shell namespace extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)". There are several .NET resources for writing these explorer extensions.

- http://namespaceextension.codeplex.com/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1649/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Namespace-Ex
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13515/A-Namespace-Extension-Toolkit
  And perhaps many more.

Of course - we must [remember](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx) why it isn't a good idea to write explorer extensions in .NET.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In fairness .NET 4 has fixed that issue, but I agree: don't do it in .NET.